# How to turn on intellisense for custom master page(.master) in Visual Studio Code

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio intellisense is working. But in Visual Studio Code intellisense for .master files is not working.

VSCode
[image]
Visual Studio 2015
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install SPGo plugin in VSCode:

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you Jerry. This plugin is very nice for SharePoint developing!